# What do ACK, SB, SF, LG, RES mean in Sigfox network?

Tags: networking, software, lpwan, sigfox

I found these abbreviations in [an official documentation](https://www.disk91.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/4967675830228422064.pdf) and I don't know what they are stand for.

[image]

Can you explain it to me please? I know that it is basic question.

Comment: Can you share that document? Does not it have a list of abbrevation?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the document (link), as long as that is missing the question cannot be reopened for lack of context.

Comment: Fixed that for you. I editted your question to add the link to the referenced document. I tried a few search engines, and that is the only document or web page which references those terms, so the correct answer is - you will have to ask SigFox

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately this is not a complete answer, I will update it if I get more information. As for now, based on the [Sigfox AT command descriptions](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/Sigfox-AT-commands.html).

> `AT$SB=bit[.bit]`     Send a Bit Status (0 or 1).
>
> `AT$SF=frame[.bit]`   Used
>   to send payload data or frame of size 1 to 12 bytes. For example:
>   `AT$SF=gghh1234`

- SB means Status Bit message
- SF means Sigfox Frame

  > An uplink message has up to 12-bytes payload and takes an average 2s
  >   over the air to reach the base stations which monitors the spectrum
  >   looking for UNB signals to demodulate. For a 12-byte data payload, a
  >   Sigfox frame will use 26 bytes in total. [source](https://www.sigfox.com/en/sigfox-iot-technology-overview)

---

- ACK, a device can request acknowledgement from the network by setting the ACK flag in the message.

  > The Downstream messages are, in fact, frame acknowledgment. It means
  >   that to receive a message on the device, you have to send one
  >   indicating the Sigfox network you are expecting a ack.
  >
  > This ack is a 8bytes message the network can send directly with
  >   predefined value like current time or any used defined fixed value. It
  >   can also be a dynamic message sent by your own backend.
  >
  > The device is sending a message with ack flag activated and then turn
  >   into receive mode during 25 seconds, looking for the network
  >   acknowledgment. This one received it will go back sleeping. Between
  >   the end of the send and the begin or the receive you have about 15
  >   seconds sleep. [source](https://www.disk91.com/2014/technology/internet-of-things-technology/sigfox-downlink-howto/)

Comment: RES may be response - part of the flow control similar to ACK.